# Is it possible to use Arduino UNO programmer for other AVR microcontrollers?

Tags: avr

I got an Arduino UNO which I started using with microc for avr to add more customizations.
I'm wondering if it is possible to use the Arduino UNO programmer to program other AVR microcontrollers (I know that it is possible using ATmega 328p and 168).

Comment: Are you using serial port programming or ISP?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking. Are you familiar with: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Comment: yeah i am using arduno isp.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by 'other AVR microcontrollers'. Can you please specify one specific AVR you plan to program using Arduino Uno?

Answer (score 2):

The AVR microcontrollers that support ISP are all tinyAVRs other than the 4/5/9/10/20/40, and all megaAVRs.

The ATtiny4/5/9/10/20/40 requires TPI (Tiny Programming Interface). AVR XMEGA devices require the use of PDI (Program and Debug Interface). Neither can be programmed using ArduinoISP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using avrisp you can basically program every AVR compatible with ISP protocol.

For example you can program ATTINY85, ATMEGA8, ATMEGA16 etc...
Basically for cheap and usable project with a usable flash size i use ATMEGA8 or 88.
Avoid ATMEGA48, you have only 4 kb of flash and that mean you can not do anything instead of blinking LED.

Another way to do this is by using Raspberry pi GPIO for burning code on AVR.

Here is some doc [from ozzmaker](http://ozzmaker.com/program-avr-using-raspberry-pi-gpio/)